# Empty Space / Folder Image when SharePoint Online list on template is empty

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, customization

When I create a list on a template I don't like this additional space that's added at the bottom of the list when it is still empty.  The empty folder with the arrow pointing in it.  SO ANNOYING.  It pushes valuable information down and is completely unnecessary. Please tell me someone knows how to remove it?

[image]

Comment: That entire section provides drag-and-drop capability, so that people can upload files from their desktop quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure if you can solve this with OOTB settings, however, One possible solution is that you could load some jQuery to hide these element which would slide the page back up.

I am not sure your level of experience, but you could identify the containing div, or the image that is showing

**For example:**

IN chrome, right click the elements -> Inspect -> get the id or class and then you can put code on your page like this in a Snippet web part.

If you don't already load jQuery on the page, then you will have to link to it

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){

                   $('#elementID').hide();
                   //or
                   $('.elementClass').hide();

            })
</script>
```